# How to pronounce ראב"ד

Tags: pronunciation

I know this seems like a funny question, but it has always bothered me. What is the proper way to pronounce ראב"ד ? From a simple reading it would seem Ravaad makes the most sense ,but in the yeshiva world he is called the Ryevid (hard to convey the actual pronunciation; think **Rye**-bread, **vid**eo). Any insights to this?

*another such idea is  Masheches Yoma and Yuma

Comment: It’s not really a word so would it necessarily have a “correct” pronunciation?

Comment: I just found an amazing source for this. In making of a Gadol page 166 in the improved edition.  Rav Nosson explains that his father Rav Yaakov noted that all abbreviations are sounded with a Shva and Pasach, just like D'tzach Adash... and RashBam,RamBam. So from this teaching it seems that ראב"ד should be pronounced RaaVad,and Ritvuh as RitvAh,and RasBah instead of Rashbuh,I found it to be very intresting.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as pointed out in the comments, ראב''ד is not a word, it's an acronym for רב אברהם בן דוד.

But when it is pronounced, it is properly pronounced "Ra'avad". Of course, in the yeshiva world this is often mispronounced, as are other words with a double "a" sound. For instance, מעשה becomes "maiseh" instead of "ma'aseh". מעריב becomes "mairiv" instead of "ma'ariv".
So naturally "Ra'avad" becomes "Raivid"!

Comment: How do you know it is properly pronounced Ra'avad,and not Ravaad

Comment: Maybe not. Maybe those are the Ayin sound surviving, or some yiddish variation of it. מעשה מעריב

Comment: @sam because the Aleph is between the Resh and Beis, not between the Beis and Daled...

Comment: @DoubleAA I think it probably comes from Yiddish, but the question is where did Yiddish get it from?

Comment: "when it is pronounced, it is properly pronounced ’Ra'avad'": can you support this claim? Maybe it's "ra'aved" with a _tzere_?

Comment: How do you know that one of these days of pronouncing this word is wrong?

Comment: I just found an amazing source for this. In making of a Gadol page 166 in the improved edition. Rav Nosson explains that his father Rav Yaakov noted that all abbreviations are sounded with a Shva and Pasach, just like D'tzach Adash... and RashBam,RamBam. So from this teaching it seems that ראב"ד should be pronounced RaaVad,and Ritvuh as RitvAh,and RasBah instead of Rashbuh,I found it to be very intresting.